# django select records from multiple tables with same foreign key

Tags: django, inner-join, django-queryset

I would like to execute a single query in Django which retrieves related data, by foreign key, in multiple tables. At present I have to run a query on each table e.g. (House, Furniture, People) using the House number as a filter.

In SQL I can do this in one query like this:

```
SELECT house.number, house.number_of_rooms, furniture.type, people.name
FROM (house INNER JOIN furniture ON house.number = furniture.house_number) 
INNER JOIN people ON house.number = people.house_number
WHERE (((house.number)="21"));
```

Can this be done in Django?

See example models below:

```
class House(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField('House Number', max_length=10, blank=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    number_of_rooms = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)

class Furniture(models.Model):
    house_number = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type = models.CharField('Furniture Type', max_length=50)

class People(models.Model):
    house_number = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your models add `related_name` arguments for foreign keys, so that you can retrieve the objects related to the `House()` instance.

```
class Furniture(models.Model):
    house_number = models.ForeignKey(House, related_name='house_furniture', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type = models.CharField('Furniture Type', max_length=50)

class People(models.Model):
    house_number = models.ForeignKey(House, related_name='house_people', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=50)
```

Then run the migration using following commands.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then create a new **serializers.py** module in the same app.

```
#import models Furniture, People, house

from rest_framework import serializers

class FurnitureSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Furniture
        fields = ['type'] # if you want all the fields of model than user '__all__'.

class PeopleSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = People
        fields = ['first_name'] # if you want all the fields of model than user '__all__'.

class HouseSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    house_furniture = FurnitureSerializer(many=True)
    house_people = PeopleSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Furniture
        fields = ['number', 'number_of_rooms', 'house_furniture', 'house_people']
```

Now, in your **views.py** you can simply query on model `House` and serializer the result with `HouseSerializer()`.

#import models from models.py
#import serializer from serializers.py

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class ListHouseView(ListAPIView):

```
serializer_class = HouseSerializer
queryset = House.objects.filter() #here you can apply filters on the fields of house model and user using related_name you can filter on other related models as well.
```

Now, simply call ad this in your app's **urls.py**

```
url_pattern = [
    path('list-house/', ListHouseView.as_view()),
]
```

Make sure that have a path in your project's **urls.py** to reach this app's **urls.py**.

Answer (score 0):

The usual Django way of dealing with this is `Queryset.prefetch_related()` and iterating through Python (unless you're using Postgres, which has its own solution of `ArrayAgg`). Given your models, it'll cost three queries, but you won't have to deal with de-normalized row results.

```
h = House.objects.prefetch_related('furniture_set', 'people_set').get(number='21')
for furniture in house.furniture_set.all():
    print(furniture)
for person in house.people_set.all():
    print(people)
```

`prefetch_related()` caches the results and does the "joining" in Python once the queryset is evaluated, so iterating through the reverse relationships won't incur additional queries, and you're free to structure/serialize the data however you like. The raw SQL from this is something like:

```
SELECT house.number, house.number_of_rooms FROM house WHERE house.number = '1'
SELECT furniture.id, furniture.house_number_id, furniture.type FROM furniture WHERE furniture.house_number_id IN ('1')
SELECT people.id, people.house_number_id, people.first_name FROM people WHERE people.house_number_id IN ('1')
```

But Django does that behind-the-scenes so that you can just deal with a model instance in Python.